# ASP.NET MVC. CodeFirst. Связь один к одному

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть готовая база данных. Необходимо к ней сделать Web-приложение на ASP.NET MVC. Подключаю базу в режиме CodeFirst, но никак не получается связать две таблицы имеющие связь Один-к-одному.
Таблицы следующие

```sql
CREATE TABLE USERS (
   ID_U                INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ID_EMPLOYEE         INTEGER,
   PW                  VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT ''
);
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_USERS PRIMARY KEY (ID_U);
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERS_1 FOREIGN KEY (ID_EMPLOYEE) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (ID_EM) ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
   ID_EM        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   LAST_NAME    VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
   FIRST_NAME   VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
   MIDDLE_NAME  VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID_EM);
```

Создаю следующие классы:

```
[Table("USERS")]
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("ID_U")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("PW"), StringLength(250)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_EMPLOYEE")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

[Table("EMPLOYEE")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key, Column("ID_EM")]        
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Column("LAST_NAME"), StringLength(250)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("FIRST_NAME"), StringLength(250)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("MIDDLE_NAME"), StringLength(250)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

В DbContext прописываю

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

В контроллере код для теста

```
 private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    foreach (User us in db.Users)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = us.Employee.FirstName;
    }
    return View();
 }
```

При считывании данных в классе User свойство Employee всегда null. 
Не пойму как правильно прописать связи, чтобы в User.Employee были данные.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь и советы.

Comment: что бы получить *Employee* Вам надо либо воспользоваться *lazy loading* либо сделать *include* т.е. что то типа `db.Users.Include("Employees")` или `db.Users.Include(x=>x.Employee)`

Comment: У вас ошибка в вопросе: вы пишите про связь один-к-одному, но по факту у вас один-ко-многим. Связь 1-к-1 - это всегда связь по первичным ключам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тут все-таки один из вариантов связи 1-к-1, т.к. для связи 1-ко-многим все-таки требуется наличие еще одной таблицы

Comment: @FMA, вы что-то путаете. Смотрите: что мешает мне поставить в базе одинаковые значения `EmployeeId` у разных пользователей? Никто. Значит, одной записи `Employee` может соответствовать много записей `User`. А значит, это обычное соотношение один-ко-многим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF не подгружает связанные сущности по умолчанию. Т.е. нужно или включить Lazy Loading, сделав свойство виртуальным - тогда EF заменит его на прокси, который подгрузится при обращении:

```
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

или явно обозначить, что вы хотите загрузить данные

```
foreach (User us in db.Users.Include("Employee")) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ForeignKey("ID_EMPLOYEE")]
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

[Column("ID_EMPLOYEE")]
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

Вот так должно работать